# Return JsonResult to controller from ADO entity model and ouput as partialview to DevExtreme chart

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, edmx, chart.js

I have an ADO Entity model in my ASP.NET MVC application. In the database, I have a table with data that I would like to output to ChartJS widget to display in my view. I would like to do this using AngularJS two way data binding. I would like to use a GET statement in my controller to pull the data I need using a JsonResult.  I was told not to create a new variable in the view. I have set up my connectioin to database and is working. I have referenced the following: ChartJS, AngularJS, Dx, JQuery and a few more.

Comment: Although, I did not receive any replies...I will go ahead and update as I move along for anyone who is interested.  I have created my JSON object in my controller.  Next, I will be using my JSON object in an AngularJS controller.  Here is what the Json Result looks like so far...

Comment: public JsonResult PostChart(int product_id)
        {
            Object prod = null;
            using (ProductOrderEntities db = new ProductOrderEntities())
            {
                var product = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.product_id == product_id);
                prod = new {productID = product.product_id, productName = product.product_name, productPrice = product.product_cost, productDescription = product.product_type};                
            }
            return Json(prod, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }